# EXCEL formula if condition

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

Is there a way to simplify the below formula in the picture, and how do you include a condition to also move the "actual payment date" to next day if it fall on any Holiday dates?

```
=F106+IF($C$100="Next",IF(TEXT(G106,"DDD")="Sat",2,IF(TEXT(G106,"ddd")="Sun",1,0)),IF($C$100="Previous",IF(TEXT(G106,"ddd")="Sat",-1,IF(TEXT(G106,"ddd")="Sun",-2,0))))
```

[image: Picture]

Comment: No formula included, below or anywhere else.

Comment: Use `=IFS()` for nested if-then-else conditions.

Comment: The formula is in the image; currently i have it as follows:
=F106+IF($C$100="Next",IF(TEXT(G106,"DDD")="Sat",2,IF(TEXT(G106,"ddd")="Sun",1,0)),IF($C$100="Previous",IF(TEXT(G106,"ddd")="Sat",-1,IF(TEXT(G106,"ddd")="Sun",-2,0))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use WORKDAY to return the next or previous workday and it includes a criterion that accepts a range of dates for holidays:

```
=IF($C$100="Next",WORKDAY(F106-1,1,$L$106:$L$110),WORKDAY(F106+1,-1,$L$106:$L$110))
```

Where `$L$106:$L$110` is the range with your holiday dates.

Comment: Thank you Scott, can this formula include additional range of holiday dates, for example holidays from different countries?

Comment: you can include a nested if to return the correct range ie: in place of `$L$106:$L$110` you would use: `IF($ZZ$1="UK",$L$106:$L$110,IF($ZZ$1="USA",$H$106:$H$110))` and nest more for other countries.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to create a new question with its own [mcve]  This is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I used following formula and it's not working for the second and third range of countries having holidays; and what does the -1 and +1 mean?
=IF($1C$100="Next",WORKDAY(F106-1,1,IF($L$105="UK",$L$106:$L$138,IF($O$105="US",$O$106:$O$142,IF(R105="LUXEMBOURG",$R$106:$R$140))))),WORKDAY(F106+1,1,IF($L$105="UK",$L$106:$L$138,IF($O$105="US",$O$106:$O$142,IF(R105="LUXEMBOURG",$R$106:$R$140)))))

Comment: I would assume that you choose the holidays to use, which means the part `##="SomeCountry"` should be referring to the same cell and one would change that cell to pick which holidays they want.  If you want to include them all, then just put them in the same range and refer to the full range.